# Can I install firebase CLI using yarn as package manager?

Tags: firebase, firebase-cli

Can I install firebase CLI using yarn as package manager? Actually i've tried to search for it but instead of finding a command to install firebase tools using yarn I found a command that simply installs firebase using yarn

this is the command :

```
yarn add firebase
```

that's why i'm confused is it same? or is it not possible to install firebase tools using yarn as a package manager?

Comment: Have you tried running `yarn add firebase-tools`?

Comment: yes I tried and it worked

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to install firebase cli is to install the firebase-tools package.

```
yarn add firebase-tools
```

Other options are listed in the official documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli